# Which is the proper way to use "correct" after asking question in a sentence?

Tags: american-english, punctuation, question-tags

Here are some example sentences:

> Your name is John, correct?
>   You're married, correct?

I am even curious about using ", right" instead of the other in certain sentences. Is the comma before "correct" necessary, or is there some other proper way to compose it?

Comment: You haven't asked Mr. Google, correct? It sounds fine to my non-native ears anyway. :)

Comment: I have made a few inquiries on Google, but to no avail, nothing. StackExchange is a place of knowledge in my opinion.

Comment: "Correct?", when used in the above sense, means "Is this true?"  It can of course also be used as a response to a query, meaning "What you just said is true."

Answer (score 4):

Your examples sound fine to me. Here are other examples.

**Am I right?** (Isn't that so? Right? Correct? etc.) — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Am+I+right%3F)

> *informal*  A way of demanding a response and stimulating further conversation.

And yes, a comma would be good.

> Your name is John, correct?

Or you can separate them like this.

> Your name is John. Correct?

It's called a **tag question** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question)

> A question tag or tag question (also known as tail question) is a grammatical structure in which a declarative statement or an imperative is turned into a question by adding an interrogative fragment (the "tag").
>
> For example, in the sentence "*You're John, aren't you?*", the statement "*You're John*" is turned into a question by the tag "*aren't you*".

Answer (score 1):

I believe question tags will fit here.

> You're married, aren't you?
>
> Your name is john, isn't it?

[Wiki Link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question)